# datatables default sort (asc/desc) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i tried to fetch data to a mysql table using this

```
$query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id_user ASC");
```

this is my table structure

users

```
id_user  | INT auto-increment
username | varchar
password | varchar
nama     | varchar
role     | varchar
status   | SET
```

but the displayed data order is ordered like this 1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
(13 data in database)

Edit: full code to display

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="center">ID</th>
                <th align="center">Username</th>
                <th align="center">Nama</th>
                <th align="center">Role</th>
                <th width="13%" align="center">Status</th>      
                <th width="7%" align="center">Edit</th> 
                <th width="8%" align="center">Hapus</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        $query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id_user ASC");
        while($row=$query->fetch()){
            $id=$row['id_user'];
            $name=$row['username'];
            $nama=$row['nama'];
            $role=$row['role'];
            $status=$row['status'];
        ?>  
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;<?php echo $id ;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;<?php echo $name ;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;<?php echo $nama ;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;<?php echo $role ;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;<?php echo $status ;?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="edituser.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"><button class="alert-success">Edit</button></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="deleteuser.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&role=<?php echo $role;?>" onclick="return confirm('Apa anda yakin akan menghapus user ini?');"><button class="alert-success">Delete</button></a></td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </table>
```

added script for datatable but it return error cannon reinitialize data table

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').dataTable({
   "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]]
   });    
  });
```

Comment: id_user   data type?

Comment: Is id_user a string?

Comment: its int with auto-inc properties

Comment: If it is int it should print the users in correct order. Show us your entire code. @BillyAnthony

Comment: @BillyAnthony, if you execute the same query `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id_user ASC` in phpmyadmin, do you get the same order of records?

Comment: its working as intended in phpmyadmin, but not working in page

Comment: i think this issue occurred  during display record

Comment: $row=$query->fetch(); and print_r($row);die();  and check it`s proper or not

Comment: Can you print_r($row['is_user']); and see if it prints all rows in the desired sequence?

Comment: You might be accessing a different database in the code....?

Comment: table id="example" you can set any script on table id?

Comment: Do you have some kind of custom db connection object which could be reordering the records before returning them?

Comment: @ReenaMori with print_r($row);die(); the array is ordered asc

Comment: @Kickstart nope

Comment: try display record using other lopping like foreach,for

Comment: with print_r($row['id_user'] its giving proper order output.. maybe jquery.datatable.js is messing with the order

Comment: yes, i already asked you :- can you add any script on table if you are using datatable you need to set defualt ordring like this :"order": [[ 0, "asc" ]]

Comment: Then let's tag this question properly because it does not have anything to do with MySQL or php. Pls add the **relevant** client side code that displays the results.

Comment: please share your full html code with script & try with : <table data-order='[[ 1, "asc" ]]'> in your html

Comment: an also, remove &nbsp; from every <td>

Comment: @ReenaMori only removing the $nbsp solve the problem!! please create an answer and i will accept it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
 <td>
   <?php echo $id ;?>
  </td>
```

Just remove   from display record

for centered data you can use the `text-center` bootstrap class

Answer (score 4):

Male sure "id_user" field is of "int" data type in DB Table.

And after that try using "aaSorting". Ref: http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
    } );
} );
```